# Docking wear app to watch face

Tags: wear-os, dockable

Apologies for an 'open' question, but can anyone provider pointers on how to 'dock' my app to the Android Wear watch face?

Essentially, I want users of the application to be able to swipe left to right (or vice-versa) from the edge of the screen to open the application, compared to having to scroll the list of applications after tapping the watch face.

I've seen this implemented in another wear app, but don't know the right terminology to produce meaningful results in Google. Is it a wallpaper service, specific view type, touch listerner service etc?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't receive touch events inside the `WatchFaceService`, touch delivery is disabled.

I can't say for sure how the app you saw implemented the desired behavior, but it probably did by inserting views directly into the `WindowManager` from a `Service`.

Checkout this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3vHjxonOeg
I don't know how well the [Standout library](https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut/tree/master/library/src/wei/mark/standout) does its job, but it should give you enough examples to figure out yourself, how to add views to the `WindowManager`.